# How would I enable and disable a function by using the OnKeyDown in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm fairly new to Visual Studio and C++ in general and am just trying to do some basic stuff with it. Right now I'm trying to figure out how I could enable the function when pressing 'e' and then disabling it when pressing 'd'. This is the code for the functions:

```
    void draw_line_paint(HDC DC, int x, int y, int a, int b, COLORREF color)
{
    HPEN Stift = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, color);
    SelectObject(DC, Stift);
    MoveToEx(DC, x, y, NULL);
    LineTo(DC, a, b);
    DeleteObject(Stift);
}
//*************************************************************************
void OnKeyDown(HWND hwnd, UINT vk, BOOL fDown, int cRepeat, UINT flags)
    {

    switch (vk)
        {

            case 68://d
                //disable the function
                break;
            case 69://e
                //enable the function
                break;

            default:break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: instead of `case 68:` and a comment explaining what you are doing, use `case 'd':`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what a *flag* is in programming? It's a boolean variable that can be used to enable or disable something. Set or clear the flag (make it true or false) and check it in the function that you want enabled/disabled.